# MVVM MEF WindowFormHost

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mef

I am currently trying to design an application that loads viewmodels through MEF imports.

So far so good, I navigate from viewmodel to viewmodel, having loaded each vm datatemplate through dictionaries.

Each time I navigate, I modify the content of the main contentPresenter in my Shell (MainWindow).

One of the viewmodel allows me to display a WindowFormHost for an activeX control (such as acrobat reader for example). Since WindowFormHost does not allow binding, I created the windowFormHost in the viewmodel and binded it to a ContentPresenter in the view.

And here is where it fails : when coming back to the same viewmodel, the view is created again... throwing a “Element is already the child of another element.” error.

How can I prevent that ? Should I unload WindowFormHost when view is reloaded ? Or Can I keep view instances so that I keep only one instance for each view and let data binding update controls ? (It looks better for memory consumption).

Thanks for your help !

[EDIT]

Loaded dictionary :

```
<DataTemplate x:Shared="False" DataType="{x:Type vm:DAVPDC3DVIAControlViewModel}">
    <vw:MyUserControl />
</DataTemplate>
```

View :

```
<DockPanel>
    <ContentControl Name="WFH3DVia" Content="{Binding Path=Control3DVIA, Mode=OneWay} </ContentControl>"
    <!--<WindowsFormsHost Name="WFH3DVia"></WindowsFormsHost>-->
</DockPanel>
```

VM (singleton, mef module) :

```
[Export(typeof(IDAVPDC3DVIAControl))]
public partial class DAVPDC3DVIAControlViewModel : ViewModelBase, IViewModel, IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification
```

VM (main window)

```
[Export]
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase, IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification
```

// CurrentUC binds main widow view to controller active viewmodel

```
    public IViewModel CurrentUC
    {
        get
        {
            return myAddinManager.CurrentVM;
        }
    }
```

Main view :

Controler (displays module on event) :

```
    private void ModuleReadyEventAction(string iModuleName)
    {
        if (null != this.Modules && this.Modules.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in Modules)
            {
                IBaseModule ibasemodule = item as IBaseModule;
                if (null != ibasemodule)
                {
                    Type tp = ibasemodule.GetType();
                    if (0 == tp.Name.CompareTo(iModuleName))
                    {
                        CurrentVM = ibasemodule.GetViewModel();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also working on a project in WPF using Prism v4 and MVVM (except I'm using Unity). I also have at least two controls that I need to use which are Windows Forms controls that must be hosted in a WindowsFormsHost. Let me explain my thoughts on the process..

It seems to me, that you are trying to avoid any code in your View's code behind. That's the only reason I can think of that you are moving your WindowsFormsHost into your ViewModel. I think that this is fundamentally the wrong approach. The WindowsFormsHost exists for the reason of displaying a graphical Windows Forms control. Therefore, it belongs in the view!

Now, I understand the appeal of DataBindings. Trust me, I've wanted to able to DataBind many parts of my WindowForms control. Of course, to accept a WPF data binding the property must be a dependency property on a dependency object. The easiest solution, which is not unreasonable, is to simply add the code to configure your windows forms control in the code behind for your view. Adding your UI logic into your ViewModel is an actual violation of the MVVM design pattern, while adding code behind is **not.** (And in some cases is the best approach)

I've seen possible hacks to try to get around this limitation. Including using "proxies" which inject a databinding, or perhaps extending WindowsFormsHost and adding DependencyProperties which wrap a specific hosted control's properties, or writing classes using reflection and trying to throw in windows forms bindings. However, nothing I've seen can solve the problem completely. For example, my windows forms control can contain other graphical components, and those components would need to support binding as well.

The simplest approach is to simply synchronize your view with your viewmodel in your view's code behind. Your view model can keep the file or document that is open, filename, title, etc., but leave the display and display related controls up to the View.

Last, let me comment more directly on your question. I would need to see how you are registering your View and ViewModel with the MEF Container and how you are navigating to understand why you are receiving that error. It would seem to me that either your view or view model is getting created more than once, while the other is not. Are these registered as singleton types? Regardless, I stand by what I said about not including the WindowsFormsHost in your ViewModel.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I knew that creating the host in the vm was breaking the mvvm laws :) I will do as you suggest, put the necessary code in the code behind of the view.

Comment: I Added some code. I already tried to add mef export on the view, but it does not change it being created more than once !

Comment: I'm not sure that the code you provided shows me enough of what's going on. As far as I know MEF defaults to singleton registration with the container. Are you creating your View or your ViewModel first? Is your View a data template only? or does it now derive from UserControl and include a WindowsFormsHost with if-necessary code behind? If I were you, I'd refer to this book [Microsoft Prism v4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx) Especially, chapter 3.

Comment: OK : "Data templates can be thought of as views that do not have any code-behind. They are designed to bind to a specific
view model type whenever one is required to be displayed in the UI. At run time, the view, as defined by the data
template, will be automatically instantiated and its data context set to the corresponding view model." I guess this is the way it has to be, if i want a single view instance, I have to get rid of the datatemplate :( Thanks for your help !

Comment: ViewModel is created first (resolved by mef container, and yes it is a singleton by default). The view is a userControl referenced by the datatemplate, wpf instanciates it for me when I put my vm in the contentPresenter.